# React-router-dom calls constructor first before unmounting the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I want my component to re-render every time when I click on the link in the header. So I used the component props in `route` to rerender my component.

```
<Route
 exact
 path="/assets"
 component={props => (<AssetsView {...props} />)}
/>
```

In the docs it is stated that

> This results in the existing component unmounting and the new
>   component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.

But, when I click the Link, the constructor is called first, followed by componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount is the last lifecycle to be called.

I have 2 components Edit and Table view and I navigate between these two components using react-router-dom. When I am in Edit component I want to change the redux state on unmount based on the condition before the Table component mounts and use the changed redux state in the initial state (using Constructor) of Table component. How can this be achieved?

sample program - https://codesandbox.io/s/kmy387l59o

Did anyone face this problem?

Comment: I guess you shouldn't rely on the precedence you expect. You possibly have XY problem and don't need to re-mount the component at all (this seems fishy). Consider reasking the question with your real problem instead. It likely can be solved in more conventional way.

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to render everytime ?

Comment: I want to reset the existing state of the component and make an API call in componentDidMount

Answer (score 1):

From React16 onwards componentWillUnmount is asynchronous that's why it is called after next components componentWillMount. For more details check out the discussion [here.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11106)

> In React 15, ComponentWillUnmount called first before the rendering of
>   next component in DOM. In the current version (v16),
>   ComponentWillUnmount was called after the mounting of next component.